# incoming call to the server from WAN drop after some sconds

Tags: asterisk, voip, freepbx, elastix

i use Elastix 2.4.0 with a static public IP
all call on LAN no problem
any out call from any extension on the LAN To any extension on WAN(internet) no problem
any call from any extension on WAN(internet) to any other extension the call drop off after some seconds.

when i change sip.config to:

localnet=192.168.1.20/255.255.255.0

calls not drop off but no voice

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not programming question, but debug question

You have ensure

1) you provided external ip to asterisk via externaddress= param

2) your firewall not block sip protocol nor change it(sip alg or similar algorithm not enabled on firewall)

Comment: Sorry about this question in wrong place, and Thank you so much about your replay, the problem in "SIP Application Layer Gateway" when i turn it on the call connect perfect without any drop off

Comment: Yes, SIP ALG on most routers designed to support client soft(softphone) and not understand server side(asterisk)